# Prometheus Alert Manager error "component=cluster err="couldn't deduce an advertise address" and "unable to initialize gossip mesh"

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I'm new to Prometheus and I'm trying to install Alert Manager module.

Using Prometheus 2.19.2, Node exporter 1.0.1 and Alert Manager 0.21.0 on Debian 10.

Configuration files:

Prometheus:

```
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      - localhost:9093"
```

Alert Manager:

```
global:
  smtp_smarthost: 'localhost:25'
  smtp_from: 'alertmanager@domain.com'
  smtp_auth_username: ''
  smtp_auth_password: ''
  smtp_require_tls: false

templates:
- '/etc/alertmanager/template/*.tmpl'

route:
  repeat_interval: 1h
  receiver: operations-team

receivers:
- name: 'operations-team'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'postmaster@domain.com'
```

The issue is about Alert Manager service that throws an error on starting:

```
Jul  9 19:08:11 mail alertmanager[851]: level=warn ts=2020-07-09T17:08:11.887Z caller=cluster.go:154 component=cluster err="couldn't deduce an advertise address: no private IP found, explicit advertise addr not provided"

Jul  9 19:08:11 mail alertmanager[851]: level=error ts=2020-07-09T17:08:11.901Z caller=main.go:241 msg="unable to initialize gossip mesh" err="create memberlist: Failed to get final advertise address: No private IP address found, and explicit IP not provided"
```

I've been looking in Internet but haven't found a solution yet...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

you should add arg "--cluster.advertise-address=0.0.0.0:9093" when startup

Comment: Just an extra note, I had to delete the old pod in order the above to work.